# Set Windows Dialog Box Input

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to write a C# code that handles file uploading automaticly.
The follow I need to implement is to choose a file from an open file dialog:

- [The Dialog I need to control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4QVu.png)

I managed to find the window using `users32.dll` `FindWindow()` method.
But i have no idea how to set the input if the dialog and approve the chosen file (choose a file & press OK).

My Code so far:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
public const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

private void ChooseFile()
{
    // retrieve the handler of the window  
    int iHandle = FindWindow("#32770", "File Upload");
    if (iHandle > 0)
    {
        //Choose File
        //Press OK
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify my question, I don't need to open a new dialog, just to control a dialog opened by another processes (FireFox file upload dialog).

Answer (score 1):

You have C# class OpenFileDialog (http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog), not necessary for user32.dll.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do do is a bit odd. You are calling Win32 function, but all you need is to use OpenFileDialog class, which is proper .NET way here ([MSDN OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx))

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
DialogResult res = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string filePath = dlg.FileName;
    // do your upload logic here
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan.  I want to take control of a window opened by another process and not open a new dialog window, can I interact with a Dialog window using OpenFileDialog class?

Answer (score 0):

After allot of research i found the solution.

I used Windodows.Form.SendKeys class which simulates the keyboard and send the string to the focused window.

here is the code:

```
 SendKeys.SendWait(fileInfo.FullName);
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
 Thread.Sleep(5000);
```